# ElasticSearch query to bring nested data in response but not filter data if nested field does not exist

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have nested data in some documents, in some it is not. Suppose below is the mapping.

```
{
"mappings": {
         "item": {
            "properties": {
               "id": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "nestedType": {
                  "type": "nested",
                  "properties": {
                     "item1": {
                        "type": "long"
                     },
                     "item2": {
                        "type": "string"
                     }
                    }
                }
            }
         }
    }
}
```

I want to query on id basis, and want nested element to include in my response where item1 = 1234. But i do not want to filter response. If item1 != 1234 or item1 doesnot exist.

Actually, I don't want nested query to effect my Hits result. but to include inner hits if match found other no result in inner hits.

Comment: So you want to filter on  `id` and you want the nested element to be present in the response **only if**  `nestedType.item1 = 1234`? But if `nestedType.item1` is not present or has a different value than 1234, you don't want the nested element to be present in the response?

Comment: Actualy, I don't want nested query to effect my Hits result. but to include inner hits if match found other no result in inner hits.

Comment: @Val does my question clear now? Please suggest if i am missing something required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following query. This will fetch result in `inner_hits` only if it exists.

```
{
"query": {
  "bool": {
     "must": [
        {
           "term": {
              "id": "idValue"
           }
        }
     ],
     "should": [
        {
           "nested": {
              "path": "nestedType",
              "query": {
                 "match": {
                    "item2": "item2Value"
                 }
              },
              "inner_hits": {}
           }
        }
     ]
   }
 }
}
```